# How to write phone shell scripts on Android devices

Tags: android, shell, adb, at-command

I need to write a script for Android, to be downloaded using ADB, and which performs the following actions on the phone:

1. Turn off the protocol stack (equivalent to the AT command AT+CFUN=0\n)
2. Turn on the protocol stack (equivalent to the AT command AT+CFUN=1\n)
3. Establish PDP context

With devices that identify as COM-ports this is easy - just open the COM port and send the appropriate AT command. But how do I do this with an Android device?

Answer (score -1):

Script manager on android market should provide some direction, as well as a catalyst for using, writing, and scheduling such scripts.